# How to make an array of the object in such a way the object with the user repeated in a row forms a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is myArray

```js
  myObject =  [
 {data: "sdhfjd", id: 1604812217822, user: "dsfjkhjkdh", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"},
 {data: "dsgsdfgsdf", id: 1604812219627, user: "dsfjkhjkdh", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"},
 {data: "fdg", id: 1604812220204, user: "dsfjkhjkdh", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"},
 {data: "dfg", id: 1604812220601, user: "newUser", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"},
 {data: "df", id: 1604812220862, user: "dsfjkhjkdh", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"},
 {data: "g", id: 1604812221223, user: "newUser", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"},
 {data: "g", id: 1604812221530, user: "dsfjkhjkdh", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"},
]
```

I Want to iterate over the array and find the common user while iterating over it . If the user is repeated over the iteration then the user must be in one object and For example :- while iterating if the user is found same  in a row then the object should contain a arraj of the data of that user

Expected Output  :-

```js
{data: ["sdhfjd" , "dsgsdfgsdf","fdg"] , id: 1604812217822, user: "dsfjkhjkdh", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"}
 {data: "dfg", id: 1604812220601, user: "newUser", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"}
 {data: "df", id: 1604812220862, user: "dsfjkhjkdh", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"}
 {data: "g", id: 1604812221223, user: "newUser", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"}
 {data: "g", id: 1604812221530, user: "dsfjkhjkdh", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"}
```

If the user is found in the row then then the data of that user should be an array of the data.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each array element

- if the user property isn't the same as the last one, or if there is no last one, add the array element to output
- if the user is the same, add the data property to the last element's data array (making it into an array if it's currently a string)

```js
const myArray =  [
 {data: "sdhfjd", id: 1604812217822, user: "dsfjkhjkdh", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"},
 {data: "dsgsdfgsdf", id: 1604812219627, user: "dsfjkhjkdh", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"},
 {data: "fdg", id: 1604812220204, user: "dsfjkhjkdh", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"},
 {data: "dfg", id: 1604812220601, user: "newUser", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"},
 {data: "df", id: 1604812220862, user: "dsfjkhjkdh", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"},
 {data: "g", id: 1604812221223, user: "newUser", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"},
 {data: "g", id: 1604812221530, user: "dsfjkhjkdh", userLogo: "jhjkahdsfj"},
];

let currentUser = "";
const output = [];

for (el of myArray) {
  if (el.user !== currentUser) {
    output.push(el);
    currentUser = el.user;
  } else {
    const last = output[output.length - 1];
    if (typeof last.data === "string") {
      last.data = [last.data];
    }
    last.data.push(el.data);
  }
}
 
console.log(output);
```